# _self property did not fetch while getting the data across partition

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a class which I have inherited from Document class to access the Resource class property.

```
public class UserProducts : Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string DocumentType { get { return CardInboxDocumentTypes.UserProducts ; } private set { } }//just a enum to stored the document tyype

    public string UserId { get; set; }//partition key 

    Public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

As the user update, it's Username I need to find all the UserProducts belongs to the user and update the Username on each document. to achieve this I had fetched the documents like this

```
IEnumerable<UserProducts> UserProductslist = await GetItemsAsync<UserProducts >(x => x.UserId == "1234" && x.DocumentType == CardInboxDocumentTypes.UserProducts );

 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri:
             UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId: _databaseId, collectionId: _collectionId),
            feedOptions: new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
             .Where(predicate)
             .AsDocumentQuery();

        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

because all the documents belong to the same partition so I  have used the procedure to update all the documents.so, To update all the documents I have made a dynamic list and send it to the Procedure.

```
  List<dynamic> DoctoUpdate = new List<dynamic>();
 foreach (UserProducts userProducts in UserProductslist )
            {

                userProducts.Username = "XYZ";
                DoctoUpdate.Add(appusercarddoc);
            }

 StoredProcedureResponse<dynamic> storedProcedureResponseappuser = await ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(procedureName: "sp_ReplaceDocument", partitionKey: "1234", documentList: DoctoUpdate);


public async Task<StoredProcedureResponse<dynamic>> ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(string procedureName, string partitionKey, List<dynamic> documentList)
    {
        StoredProcedure storedProcedure = _client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(_documentCollection.StoredProceduresLink)
                                .Where(sp => sp.Id == procedureName)
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .FirstOrDefault();
        return await _client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(storedProcedureLink: storedProcedure.SelfLink, options: new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) }, procedureParams: documentList);
    }
```

Stored procedure

```
function replaceDocument(docs) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var dbDocument
var count = 0;
if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

var docsLength = docs.length;
if (docsLength == 0) {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    return;
}
tryReplaceDoc(docs[count], callback);
function tryReplaceDoc(doc, callback) {

    var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(doc._self, doc, callback);

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
}
function callback(err, doc, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
    count++;
    if (count >= docsLength) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    } else {
        tryReplaceDoc(docs[count], callback);
    }
}
```

}

I have No idea why the value is not getting updated. as per my knowledge maybe the doc._self property is not fetched. so documents did not get updated.
is anything wrong with methods which I have used or how can I update all the docs with the same partition key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get items from cosmos db you do convert objects recieved from DB to custom class `UserProducts` by specifing this class as a generic param in `ExecuteNextAsync`. Because your class doesn't have an property which is mapped to cosmos doc `_self` property - you lose this data during convertion.

and keep an eye on your foreach cycle `foreach (UserProducts userProducts in UserProductslist )`. You recreate list on each iteration.

Comment: The UserProducts class is inherited by Document class which inherited by Resource class which have the property SelfLink as [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_self")] in it and its get mapped. I can see the value in SelfLink Property of UserProducts class. @Olga Shumeliuk

Comment: ok, so the problem is that it's correct and passed to stored proc but not received by stored proc? Did you try to log in procedure what you received there?

Comment: I have no idea but the problem was as the classes are inherited from Document class. the items which are fetched from the ExecuteNextAsync are storing internally another copy of the same properties and it does not get updated after the property update. To Solve this I have to remove Document class inheritance and add them property which I needed into my model like (Etag, _self)